# Typed declaration error in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using beanshell Postprocessor to write into Excel sheet but i am getting "Typed variable declaration" error. What is Typed declaration error and how can i resolve it ?

```
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
    import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;

    vars.put("ActualResponseTime", String.valueOf(prev.getTime()));

    String v1=vars.get("ExpectedResponseTime");
    String v2=vars.get("ActualResponseTime");


    FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream("C://Users//a622821//Desktop//New folder (2)//apache-jmeter-3.2//Jmeter_Project//Result.xlsx");

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);

    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);

    Cell a1 = row.getCell(0);

    a1.setCellValue(v1);

    Cell a2=row.getCell(1);

    a2.setCellValue(v2);


    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C://Users//a622821//Desktop//New folder (2)//apache-jmeter-3.2//Jmeter_Project//Result.xlsx"));
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have unnecessary parenthese in this line:

   ```
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C://Users//a622821//Desktop//New folder (2)//apache-jmeter-3.2//Jmeter_Project//Result.xlsx");
   ```

   the statement should end with one parenthese only
2. (this one is optional) You have extra forward slashes, you should amend your code like:

   ```
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/a622821/Desktop/New folder (2)/apache-jmeter-3.2/Jmeter_Project/Result.xlsx");
   ```

You can get more human-readable error message by putting your code inside the [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) like:

```
try {
     //your code here
} 
catch (Exception ex) {
     log.error("Beahshell failure", ex);
}
```

This way you will have the [stacktrace](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Stack_trace) in the *jmeter.log* file

---

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Elements and Groovy language for scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider moving to Groovy on next available opportunity. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details.